# Как определить тему в nextJS с кастомным хуком на zustand

Tags: nextjs, zustand

Вопрос заключается как мне определить тему для всего моего приложения, через хук если nextJs это северный рендор,

есть хранилище zustand

```
import { create } from "zustand";
import { persist } from 'zustand/middleware';

const getSystemTheme = () => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.matchMedia && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches) {
        return 'dark';
    }
    return 'light';
}

export const useThemeStore = create(persist((set, get) => ({
    theme: 'system',

    setTheme: (newTheme) => set({ theme: newTheme }),
    getSystemTheme: () => getSystemTheme(),
    getCurrentTheme: () => {
        const state = get();
        const systemTheme = getSystemTheme();
        if (state.theme === 'system') return systemTheme;
        else return state.theme;
    }
}), {
    name: 'app-theme'
}))
```

Ничего не обычного определяем тему, если системная возвращаем её, или выбранную пользователем, и как мне его определить в моем rootLayout чтобы тема определялась на всем приложение.

Легким способом можно было бы сделать так

```
import { Rubik } from 'next/font/google'
import './globals.css'
import ToastProvider from './ui/oneToasty/ToastProvider'
import { useThemeStore } from '@/store/useThemeStore'

const inter = Rubik({ subsets: ['latin', 'cyrillic'] })

export const metadata = {
    title: 'web title',
    description: 'bla bla bla',
}

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {

    const { getCurrentTheme } = useThemeStore(state => ({
        getCurrentTheme: state.getCurrentTheme,
    }))

    return (
        <html lang="en" className={getCurrentTheme()}>
            <body className={inter.className}>
                <ToastProvider options={{
                    position: 'top-right',
                    toastsDefault: {
                        width: '21rem',
                        orientation: 'horizontal',
                    }
                }}>
                    {children}
                </ToastProvider>
            </body>
        </html>
    )
}
```

Но нет useThemeStore это хук, и следовательно я получаю ошибку что его можно использовать на клиентской части, а сделать 'use client' тоже нельзя, так-как он северный и например metadata не будет....
Поэтому я в тупике